# T-SQL How to exclude a child record when it's also it's own parent record?

Tags: t-sql

I have a scenario like the following:

```
create table #Example (
    id int
    , overall_id int
    , parent_id int
    , child_id int
    );

insert into #Example values
    (1, 25963, 491575090, 491575090)
    ,(2, 25963, 547952026, 491575090)
    ,(3, 25963, 547952026, 230085039)
    ,(4, 25963, 547952026, 547952026);


select e.*
from #Example as e;


drop table #Example;
```

I want to exclude the record with id "2" because that is it's own parent record (see id "1").

I do not want to exclude 3, because the child record is not it's own parent record. And I don't want to exclude 1 and 4 because those are their own parent records.

One problem is that in my business scenario, I have no corresponding "ID" field, that is something I provided in this example so that I could refer to each row uniquely.

Any help on techniques to exclude record 2 would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question: why is someting allowed to be its own parent?

Comment: I'd guess, @squillman, an "alternative" method to denote it's the root node. Though why `NULL` isn't used instead, I'm not sure. Storing both a chuild and parent id on the same row seems like a poor diea though. Store either the child or parent, not both. Normally you store the parent in a hierarchy, as parent can have many children, but a child only has one parent.

Comment: Yeah, I usually use NULL or -1 or something to denote top level

Comment: That's correct, @Larnu. Our actual table stores this in a hierarchy. I was asking for this specific representation in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119720/how-to-display-recursive-data-set-in-a-particular-manner. What I'm after (which is beyond this question) is showing some child level attributes of a given parent, which in our case includes the "parent" itself. Point being, I know this is not best practice on "storing" top level node, this is just what I'm doing for now.

Comment: I Don't really understand the fields. It seems like `overall_id` separates this tree from other trees so they are independent? But both 1 and 4 have `child_id = parent_id`? What is the significance of that?

Comment: Each parent_id has one or more child_ids, including at least itself. This is for the purpose of associating other elements in the system to the "parent id" which may include elements from the parent itself. I don't know if that answers your question, but the comments above also get at the significance of child_id = parent_id

Comment: To elaborate just a bit more, think of it like an umbrella with the "parent id" being the end top of the umbrella. Each rib of the umbrella is like a child ID, and has information "under it" that I want to associate to the end top (parent id). Problem is that with the data I'm dealing with, the end top (parent) itself has information I want to see as if it were associated to the parent as a child (outside of this context I join to another table on the child id to get all the info/details for each "rib").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand the question, but the expected result falls out of:

```
select *
  from #Example as E
  where not exists (
    select 42
      from #Example as IE
      where
        -- There is a row that is self parenting?!
        IE.parent_id = IE.child_id and
        -- The row under consideration is related in a child/parent way?
        IE.child_id = E.child_id and
        -- It isn't the same row as we're considering.
        IE.id <> E.id );
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc1e1dd9f19a843f7e2091feebba4884).

Comment: Thanks, I know it's confusing... but I appreciate you showing me a way to solve the immediate problem at hand!

Comment: And of course I appreciate the 42 in there haha